# How do I touch every file in a directory?

Tags: bash, shell-script, exec, touch

I'm using Amazon Linux with bash shell.  I'm trying to touch every file in a certain directory, but this command is failing:

```
[myuser@mymachine scripts]$ find /usr/java/jboss/standalone/deployments/myapp.war -type f -exec touch '{}' ;
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

How do I correct the above?

Comment: Is `myapp.war` a folder?

Comment: Yes myapp.war is a folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-exec touch {} \;
```

or better yet the modern `xargs`-style

```
-exec touch {} +
```

as `;` otherwise is used by the shell for conflicting purposes.

Comment: Awesome.  Posterity will note that the complete command is "find /usr/java/jboss/standalone/deployments/myapp.war -type f -exec touch {} +"